# Formula only if formula result = >.001

Tags: excel

Trying to format a cell (throughout entire column) if formula result of SAME CELL returns value of >.001
In other words, if result is 0, nothing will be entered into cell.

Comment: Use conditional formatting based on value.

Comment: `IFERROR(1/(1/[your formula]),"")` if the formula is complex and you want it to calculate just once ;)

Answer (score 1):

The comment would work. Another way would be suppose your desired formula is `A2-B2` (you are testing whether the things are meaningfully different). Using your criterion (leaving aside whether it might be more meaningful to say the absolute value must exceed `.001`), you could rewrite your `formula` as:

```
=if(A2-B2>0.001,A2-B2,"")
```

This would generalize to any formula.